# slow building of long string using "+="

Tags: http, go, server, fasthttp

I have very slow http response performance

Used Go and Fasthttp

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/valyala/fasthttp"
)

func fastHTTPHandler(ctx *fasthttp.RequestCtx) {
    var s string = ""
    for i := 1; i <= 100000; i++ {
        s += "hello "
    }
    ctx.SetBodyString(s)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Print("Started")
    fasthttp.ListenAndServe(":8081", fastHTTPHandler)
}
```

And test it in Insomnia (Postman). Time of execution 3-4 sec. Similar code on PHP executed in 900ms.

[PHP img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQrGN.jpg)

[Golang img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRtqe.jpg)

Comment: This is a pretty pointless synthetic benchmark - do you have some real-world code with a performance problem to address?

Comment: You didn't measure where all that time was spent. Is http really the bottleneck, or string concatenation? Try with a buffer, instead of string addition.

Comment: Use [strings.Repeat("hello", 100000)](https://godoc.org/strings#Repeat) to efficient create the string.

Comment: Please don't use fasthttp. The standard http server is fast enough for all but the rarest of situations. If you need help writing performance tests, then fasthttp is not for you.

Comment: @CeriseLimón Yes, you are right. Now Golang version has 400-500ms

Comment: @CeriseLimón But if i want to write numbers? like here:
for i := 1; i <= 100000; i++ {
        s += strconv.Itoa(i) +" "
    }

Comment: `var buf []byte; for i := 1; i <= 100000; i++ { buf = strconv.AppendInt(buf, int64(i), 10); buf = append(buf, ' ') }; ctx.SetBody(buf)`  or use net/http in the somewhat obvious way by writing text the response writer in a loop.

Comment: @CeriseLimón thanks

Comment: Smells like premature optimization.

Comment: `var s strings.Builder; bte := []byte("hello"); for i := 1; i <= 100000; i++ { s.Write(bte) }; ctx.SetBodyString(s.String())` gave me 10ms

Answer (score 3):

Using `+=` in just about any language to concatenate large strings is generally going to yield terrible performance, so I wouldn't use that as my metric for anything performance related. That's why most languages have something in their standard library for building large strings. In Java you'd use a `java.lang.StringBuilder`. In Go, they added `strings.Builder` a while back. I haven't run it, but I'm fairly confident this will yield much better performance:

```
s := strings.Builder{}
for i := 1; i <= 100000; i++ {
    s.WriteString("hello ")
}
ctx.SetBodyString(s.String())
```